# Getting Invalid XML in Customer List SOAP Response

Tags: xml, magento, soap, magento-1.8

I am getting a weird issue in Magento XML response from SOAP call. I am using Magento 1.8.1. When I get the list of customers via customerCustomerList call then I receive the following invalid XML in response(See below)

This behavior is random and occurs one or two times in a day, other than this same API call works well for most of the time. Sometime it seems that invalid XML is due to password hash and sometime like below(invalid or incomplete XML node(s)):

**Request:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:customerCustomerList soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<sessionId xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">5bff6fb17eba1277154ec09885b45746</sessionId>
<filters xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="urn:filters" xs:type="type:filters">
<filter>
<associativeEntity>
<key xs:type="type:string">email</key>
<value xs:type="type:string">zahmed@folio3.com</value>
</associativeEntity>
</filter>
</filters>
</urn:customerCustomerList>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlnsSmiley FrustratedOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlnsSmiley FrustratedOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:customerCustomerListResponse>
<storeView SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:customerCustomerEntity[1]" xsi:type="ns1:customerCustomerEntityArray">
<item xsi:type="ns1:customerCustomerEntity">
<customer_id xsi:type="xsd:int">321</customer_id>
<created_at xsi:type="xsd:string">2015-02-24 12:16:11</created_at>
<updated_at xsi:type="xsd:string">2015-03-11 12:14:15</updated_at>
<store_id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</store_id>
<website_id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</website_id>
<created_in xsi:type="xsd:string">Default Store View</created_in>
<email xsi:type="xsd:string">zahmed@folio3.com</email>
<firstname xsi:type="xsd:string">Zeeshan</firstname>
<lastname xsi:type="xsd:string">Ahmed</lastname>
<group_id xsi:type="xsd:int">0</group_id>
</item>
/storeView>
</p_id xsi:type="xsd:int">0
</group_id>
<5>/ENV:Body>
<ns1:c/ENV:Envelope xmln
```

If anyone has ever faced this issue. Please let me know how to get rid of this.